# How to detect import from barrel-file (index.ts) programmatically

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I need help with Typescript-compiler understanding. I want to write a script that parse each typescript file, looking for an import declaration and if import declaration using barrel-file script should throw message about it. I dive into deep and found some solution:

```
function main3() {
    // create a program instance, which is a collection of source files
    // in this case we only have one source file
    const filePath = path.resolve('./file.ts');
    const program = _ts.createProgram([filePath], {});
    const source = program.getSourceFile(filePath);
    // helper to give us Node string type given kind
    const syntaxToKind = (kind) => {
        return _ts.SyntaxKind[kind];
    };
    // visit each node in the root AST and log its kind
    _ts.forEachChild(source, node => {
        if (_ts.isImportDeclaration(node)) {
            console.log(syntaxToKind(node.kind)); // print ImportDeclaration        
        }
    });
}
```

Question: is there a way to detect import from barrel?

Comment: I found solution. I'll write it as soon as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue. More details in github-repo: https://github.com/alxpsr/barrel-finder